# Error "No space left on device" during Docker build although there is still space

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I am trying to do a simple docker build command, however the error shows that I do not have enough space although df -h shows that I do have enough.

I have tried pruning system, network and volume. Freeing up space in general.
The following error is shown below:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 28] No space left on device

The command '/bin/sh -c pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

This is how my df -h looks like:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs           395M  760K  394M   1% /run
/dev/xvda1       16G   14G  2.0G  88% /
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       89M   89M     0 100% /snap/core/7270
/dev/loop2       89M   89M     0 100% /snap/core/7169
/dev/loop3       18M   18M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/1335
/dev/loop4       18M   18M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/1455
tmpfs           395M     0  395M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Expected result is to have a successful build.

Comment: I still think it related to your disk usage. Try to just put one package in `requirements.txt` to prove it. `2G` probably not enough for all your packages.

Comment: Can you tell the location where /var is mounted on your system?

Comment: @KalpeshJain it is mounted on /dev/xvda1. After pruning and using df -h /var, the following is shown:
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1       16G   12G  3.9G  76% /

Comment: Run `watch df -h` in a separate terminal to watch the disk space grow during the build. Also check `df -i`, as that is another cause for being out of disk space.

Comment: @Ferrybig Thank you for your helpful comments. I have figured out the problem. Do you want to change your comment into answers?

Comment: @jtan354 was this an Inode issue?

Comment: @KalpeshJain No, it was as atline and ferrybig has stated. My disk ran out of space while i executed watch df -h. Feeling a bit dumb right now!

Comment: You may post that as a solution and accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

Run `watch df -h` in a separate terminal to watch the disk space grow during the build. Also `check df -i`, as that is another cause for being out of disk space.